# Unable to run scala tests in intellij 2016.3.3 and other recent versions

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

With every recent community edition version of intellij I get this error from the scalatest runner. I'm using the maven plugin and the scala plugin. I'm using scala 11.8 also. I tried these Mac OSX versions of intellij and the corresponding scala plugin(s) that match each respective build:

**Environment:**
OSX / Mac El Capitan
Intellij Versions I replicated this with: 
 1. Community Edition 2016.2.5
 2. Community Edition 2016.3.3
 3. Intellij Community Edition 2017.1 EAP
 4. Scalatest version in maven pom.xml: 3.0.1

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/Jason/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2016.2/Scala/lib/scala-plugin-runners.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/Jason/Sites/smart-hvac/mobiledevice/target/test-classes:/Users/Jason/Sites/smart-hvac/mobiledevice/target/classes:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.4.14/akka-actor_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8/scala-library-2.11.8.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-java8-compat_2.11/0.7.0/scala-java8-compat_2.11-0.7.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-remote_2.11/2.4.14/akka-remote_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-stream_2.11/2.4.14/akka-stream_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.0/reactive-streams-1.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/ssl-config-core_2.11/0.2.1/ssl-config-core_2.11-0.2.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-protobuf_2.11/2.4.14/akka-protobuf_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.10.6.Final/netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/uncommons/maths/uncommons-maths/1.2.2a/uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/aeron/aeron-driver/1.0.4/aeron-driver-1.0.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/aeron/aeron-client/1.0.4/aeron-client-1.0.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/agrona/Agrona/0.9.0/Agrona-0.9.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-cluster-sharding_2.11/2.4.14/akka-cluster-sharding_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-cluster_2.11/2.4.14/akka-cluster_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-persistence_2.11/2.4.14/akka-persistence_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-cluster-tools_2.11/2.4.14/akka-cluster-tools_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-slf4j_2.11/2.4.14/akka-slf4j_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-stream-kafka_2.11/0.13/akka-stream-kafka_2.11-0.13.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/0.10.0.1/kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/net/jpountz/lz4/lz4/1.3.0/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.2.6/snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/lightbend/akka/akka-split-brain-resolver_2.11/1.0.0/akka-split-brain-resolver_2.11-1.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/lightbend/akka/akka-diagnostics_2.11/1.0.0/akka-diagnostics_2.11-1.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/sclasen/akka-zk-cluster-seed_2.11/0.1.8/akka-zk-cluster-seed_2.11-0.1.8.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-framework/2.11.0/curator-framework-2.11.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-client/2.11.0/curator-client-2.11.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-recipes/2.11.0/curator-recipes-2.11.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/github/dnvriend/akka-persistence-inmemory_2.11/1.3.16/akka-persistence-inmemory_2.11-1.3.16.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-persistence-query-experimental_2.11/2.4.14/akka-persistence-query-experimental_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/scalaz/scalaz-core_2.11/7.2.7/scalaz-core_2.11-7.2.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/3.1.2/cassandra-driver-core-3.1.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-core/3.1.2/metrics-core-3.1.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-ffi/2.0.7/jnr-ffi-2.0.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jffi/1.2.10/jffi-1.2.10.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jffi/1.2.10/jffi-1.2.10-native.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.3/asm-commons-5.0.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.3/asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.3/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/5.0.3/asm-util-5.0.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-x86asm/1.0.2/jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-posix/3.0.27/jnr-posix-3.0.27.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/github/jnr/jnr-constants/0.9.0/jnr-constants-0.9.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/cassandraunit/cassandra-unit/3.1.1.0/cassandra-unit-3.1.1.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/cassandra/cassandra-all/3.9/cassandra-all-3.9.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/ning/compress-lzf/0.8.4/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.1/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.4/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr/3.5.2/antlr-3.5.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/antlr/ST4/4.0.8/ST4-4.0.8.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.5.2/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.2/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.2/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/boundary/high-scale-lib/1.0.6/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.11/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/mindrot/jbcrypt/0.3m/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-jvm/3.1.0/metrics-jvm-3.1.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/addthis/metrics/reporter-config3/3.0.0/reporter-config3-3.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/addthis/metrics/reporter-config-base/3.0.0/reporter-config-base-3.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/thinkaurelius/thrift/thrift-server/0.3.7/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/lmax/disruptor/3.0.1/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/clearspring/analytics/stream/2.5.2/stream-2.5.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/6.5.7/fastutil-6.5.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/thrift/libthrift/0.9.2/libthrift-0.9.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/cassandra/cassandra-thrift/3.9/cassandra-thrift-3.9.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/carrotsearch/hppc/0.5.4/hppc-0.5.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/de/jflex/jflex/1.6.0/jflex-1.6.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.7.0/ant-1.7.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.7.0/ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/net/mintern/primitive/1.0/primitive-1.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/github/rholder/snowball-stemmer/1.3.0.581.1/snowball-stemmer-1.3.0.581.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/concurrent-trees/concurrent-trees/2.4.0/concurrent-trees-2.4.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.0.0/jna-4.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/github/jbellis/jamm/0.3.0/jamm-0.3.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/fusesource/sigar/1.6.4/sigar-1.6.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj-4.4.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/caffinitas/ohc/ohc-core/0.4.3/ohc-core-0.4.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.2.6/caffeine-2.2.6.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.0.27.Final/netty-handler-4.0.27.Final.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.0.27.Final/netty-buffer-4.0.27.Final.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.0.27.Final/netty-common-4.0.27.Final.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.0.27.Final/netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.0.27.Final/netty-codec-4.0.27.Final.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.2/aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/vivint/actor-path-log-filter-logback_2.11/0.2.4/actor-path-log-filter-logback_2.11-0.2.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/vivint/actor-path-log-filter-core_2.11/0.2.4/actor-path-log-filter-core_2.11-0.2.4.jar:/Users/Jason/Sites/smart-hvac/smart-hvac-kamon/target/classes:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-http_2.11/10.0.0/akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-http-core_2.11/10.0.0/akka-http-core_2.11-10.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-parsing_2.11/10.0.0/akka-parsing_2.11-10.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/kamon/kamon-core_2.11/0.6.3/kamon-core_2.11-0.6.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.8/HdrHistogram-2.1.8.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/kamon/kamon-statsd_2.11/0.6.3/kamon-statsd_2.11-0.6.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/kamon/kamon-system-metrics_2.11/0.6.3/kamon-system-metrics_2.11-0.6.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/io/kamon/sigar-loader/1.6.5-rev002/sigar-loader-1.6.5-rev002.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-native_2.11/3.4.0/json4s-native_2.11-3.4.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-core_2.11/3.4.0/json4s-core_2.11-3.4.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-ast_2.11/3.4.0/json4s-ast_2.11-3.4.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-scalap_2.11/3.4.0/json4s-scalap_2.11-3.4.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-jackson_2.11/3.4.0/json4s-jackson_2.11-3.4.0.jar:/Users/Jason/Sites/smart-hvac/smart-hvac-zookeeper/target/classes:/Users/Jason/Sites/smart-hvac/smart-hvac-kafka/target/classes:/Users/Jason/Sites/smart-hvac/smart-hvac-util/target/classes:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/vivint/analytics/common/analytics-core/1.71.0/analytics-core-1.71.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.7/scribe-1.3.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/de/grundid/opendatalab/geojson-jackson/1.5.1/geojson-jackson-1.5.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/vivint/analytics/common/platform-model/1.71.0/platform-model-1.71.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/vivint/analytics/occupancy/occupancy-core/1.1.8/occupancy-core-1.1.8.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-distributed-data-experimental_2.11/2.4.14/akka-distributed-data-experimental_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-http-jackson_2.11/10.0.0/akka-http-jackson_2.11-10.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/lightbend/cinnamon/cinnamon-chmetrics_2.11/2.1.3/cinnamon-chmetrics_2.11-2.1.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/lightbend/cinnamon/cinnamon-core_2.11/2.1.3/cinnamon-core_2.11-2.1.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/lightbend/cinnamon/cinnamon-logging/2.1.3/cinnamon-logging-2.1.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/lightbend/cinnamon/cinnamon-akka_2.11/2.1.3/cinnamon-akka_2.11-2.1.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/lightbend/cinnamon/cinnamon-chmetrics-statsd-reporter_2.11/2.1.3/cinnamon-chmetrics-statsd-reporter_2.11-2.1.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-persistence-cassandra_2.11/0.22/akka-persistence-cassandra_2.11-0.22.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.6.5/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.6.5.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.0/jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/rosaloves/bitlyj/2.0.0/bitlyj-2.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.7/avro-1.7.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/jeval/jeval/0.9.4/jeval-0.9.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/1.18.0-rc/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client/1.18.0-rc/google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client/1.18.0-rc/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.1/httpclient-4.0.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/httpcore-4.0.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/Jason/Sites/smart-hvac/messages/target/classes:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/outworkers/phantom-dsl_2.11/2.0.1/phantom-dsl_2.11-2.0.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/outworkers/phantom-connectors_2.11/2.0.1/phantom-connectors_2.11-2.0.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/typelevel/macro-compat_2.11/1.1.1/macro-compat_2.11-1.1.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/outworkers/diesel-engine_2.11/0.5.0/diesel-engine_2.11-0.5.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/chuusai/shapeless_2.11/2.3.2/shapeless_2.11-2.3.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.4/joda-time-2.9.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/joda/joda-convert/1.8.1/joda-convert-1.8.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-extras/3.1.0/cassandra-driver-extras-3.1.0.jar:/Users/Jason/Sites/smart-hvac/smart-hvac-util/target/test-classes:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-testkit_2.11/2.4.14/akka-testkit_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-http-testkit_2.11/10.0.0/akka-http-testkit_2.11-10.0.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-stream-testkit_2.11/2.4.14/akka-stream-testkit_2.11-2.4.14.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/net/logstash/logback/logstash-logback-encoder/4.7/logstash-logback-encoder-4.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/teambytes/logback/logback-flume-appender_2.11/0.0.9/logback-flume-appender_2.11-0.0.9.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/flume/flume-ng-sdk/1.5.0.1/flume-ng-sdk-1.5.0.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-ipc/1.7.3/avro-ipc-1.7.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.11/3.0.0-M15/scalatest_2.11-3.0.0-M15.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/scalactic/scalactic_2.11/3.0.0-M15/scalactic_2.11-3.0.0-M15.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.7/scala-reflect-2.11.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.2/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.11/1.0.4/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/net/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka_2.11/0.8.0/scalatest-embedded-kafka_2.11-0.8.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.11/0.10.0.1/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/101tec/zkclient/0.8/zkclient-0.8.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-core/2.2.0/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.7/zookeeper-3.4.7.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/threeten/threeten-extra/0.9/threeten-extra-0.9.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/config/1.3.0/config-1.3.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill_2.11/0.8.0/chill_2.11-0.8.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/kryo-shaded/3.0.3/kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/1.3.0/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.8.0/chill-java-0.8.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-akka_2.11/0.8.0/chill-akka_2.11-0.8.0.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/de/javakaffee/kryo-serializers/0.38/kryo-serializers-0.38.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/3.0.3/kryo-3.0.3.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/reflectasm/1.10.1/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:/Users/Jason/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.6.1/protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner -s com.vivint.smarthvac.actor.geo.GeoDeviceActorSpec -testName "GeoDeviceActor should receive home locations from cassandra for multiple panels" -showProgressMessages true -C org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestReporter
Testing started at 6:17 PM ...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERROR: -r has been deprecated for a very long time and is no longer supported, to prepare for reusing it for a different purpose in the near future. Please change all uses of -r to -C.
    at org.scalatest.tools.ArgsParser$.checkArgsForValidity(ArgsParser.scala:41)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:857)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

**I have attempted to fix this; here's steps I have already taken:**

 1. uninstall / reinstall intellij
 2. brew upgrade sbt
 3. various versions of intellij and this plugin
 4. I was on the 3.0.0-M15 build of scalatest; I upgraded to 3.0.1

Nothing I have tried so far works... I have seen other people post similar issues & they said that upgrading scalatest fixed this; the only upgrade I'm aware of would be to move to a snapshot version of scalatest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was that in a subproject, one of our teammates imported org.scalatest in the maven pom.xml and didn't set the scope to test... Aside from the crazy dependency conflicts this created, it was somehow overriding my version of scalatest. By setting the scope of scalatest to "test" in the subproject, this issue was fixed. i.e. Adding `<scope>test</scope>` fixed things; see the example below.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.majorVersion}</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```